# Office 2008 Mac Calendar Wizard

Tags: macos, calendar, microsoft-office-2008

I remember Office 2004 had a calendar wizard so that I can generate monthly calendars for a range of months. Like print out calendars from Jan 2010 to July 2010.

I cant seem to find the wizard or the function to create calendars in Office 2008.

Comment: Was the calendar wizard a stand alone app in Office 2004 or was it part of another app like Word, Excel or Entourage?

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate the calendars to schedule so that you can try with

`Application` >> `Microsoft Office 2008` >> `MS Entourage (like Outlook Express in Windows).`

[image]

For more, you can read about [here.](http://mac.microsoft.com/MacOffice/UARedir.aspx?target=5bbb47bc-eddd-4ebd-a4e7-2de762a1e6f31033&MODE=ct&CTT=Category&ep=9&locale=en-US&clr=99-2-0&usid=ae37b411-f5eb-4a7f-992f-2a75bb7331b7) , also [here](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/entourage2008/default.mspx#/interacting_entourage/).